# How do I send Firebase token to backend (Node / Express) via HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, https, firebase-authentication

I know this question has been asked here:
[How do I send Firebase token to backend (Node / Express) via HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941463/how-do-i-send-firebase-token-to-backend-node-express-via-https)

The best answer was not very clear to me. Can anyone please direct me in the right direction?

Just like the post above, I have client login up and working. I also found this [Verify ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) in Firebase docs, but nothing specific there as well "Send token to your backend via HTTPS"

I believe the question was answered but I'm a novice and did not understand it. Did my research, still don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-admin). Walk through it and then dig into the code, and you can see one method for handling this.

Comment: Thanks @JenPerson I did some digging and was able to solve one part of the problem. I passed the client idToken in url to the backend but did not like the idea.

I'm looking into other (server-side) firebase auth options. Thanks again for getting back.